# Data rates for each user in ADSL with discrete multitone technique

Tags: communication, telephone

I read about MODEM technology from Forouzan's 'Data Communications and Networking'. Under ADSL technology it was said- *The modulation technique that has become standard for ADSL is called the discrete
multitone technique (DMT) which combines QAM and FDM. There is no set way
that the bandwidth of a system is divided. Each system can decide on its bandwidth
division. Typically, an available bandwidth of 1.104 MHz is divided into 256 channels.
Each channel uses a bandwidth of 4.312 kHz* .
The practical downstream data rate was mentioned as 8 Mbps rather than the calculated 13.4 Mbps. When they say there are 256 channels, do each user (subsriber) get to use only one channel? In that case, each channel bandwidth is 4 kHz and baud rate is 15 bits/baud and data rate of each channel (and subsequently each user) is only 60 kbps. How does each user then avail a downstream rate of 8 Mbps?
[image: ADSL BW division]

Comment: ADSL has no concept of users, this is how the bandwidth is divided on a single circuit. Each user has their own circuit.

Comment: No, your telephone is on its own line (twisted pair).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ADSL is a point-to-point link. There's no "multiple users"; different telephone lines are different links, and the influence of one on the other is modeled as noise/inavoidable crosstalk.

So, every user gets *all* channels - or as many as the subscriber equipment ("DSL modem") and the DSL access device negotiate (some channels are not usable due to e.g. interference from radio devices, and other aren't usable due to spectrum regulation laws, and maybe the ISP just limits the number of channels based on the contract the subscriber has – but that'd be unusual).

Only in the latest standards (G.fast and on), there's a notion of multiuser access and MIMO; it's called "vectoring" in the context of DSL. Your text doesn't concern itself with that at all. (And even if it were, that's cooperative multiuser-MIMO, not OFDMA as you're hinting at.)